# Div is not visible only in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have the following css for my error div:

```
.side_error {
width: 325px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: -335px;
padding: 8px 0 0 0;
text-align: right;
color: #FF0000;
display: block;
}
```

and the following css for my table td:

```
.main_form td {
padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
position: relative;
}
```

And my HTML structure:

```
<table class="main_form" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr><td class="title_area"><h2>Create an account</h2><span>(or <a href="#">Sign In</a>)</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="side_error">please enter your full name &gt;&gt;</div><input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" class="input"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="input"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="Password" class="input"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="password" name="pass2" placeholder="Repeat Password" class="input"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="submit_area"><span><input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="yes" id="rm"><label for="rm"> I agree to <a href="#">**** Terms</a>.</label></span><input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Create Account"></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The div with class `side_error` seems to appear in every browser exactly how I want it but in Firefox (version 17.0.1) it doesn't display at all, even when I use Firebug the div doesn't get colored when hovering the html code, its like it doesn't exist at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: try removing left: -335px;?

Comment: By removing the "left" the div now appeared outside the table which is completely wrong, any idea why I'm having trouble with this only in firefox?

Comment: It seems Firefox is the only one respecting the specs here. If you're element is position:absolute and you set left:negative_value then it's going to be positioned outside the viewport.

Comment: Reuben, that is correct, it should be displayed outside the visible viewport, I think the main problem is that Firefox is the only browser that doesn't support "position:relative" on "td" element. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reorganized your css, see if this helps-

CSS-

```
.side_error 
{
  width: 325px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: -327px;
  padding: 8px 0 0 0;
  text-align: right;
  color: #FF0000;
  display: inline-block;
}
.main_form td 
{
   position:relative;
   padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}
table
{
   width:330px;
}​
```

See the working Fiddle- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YSWQP/1/)

Answer (score 0):

remove `left: -335px;` and `position: absolute;` try use `right :10px;`

or put an extra `div` around content in `td` and assign class:

```
<tr>
  <td >
    <div class="title_area">
      <h2>
       Create an account</h2><span>(or <a href="#">Sign In</a>)</span></div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Normally I'd use it like this, but I don't want the contents of the table to move and by my understanding this can only be done with "position:absolute"?